# how to store android UI component in Parcelable class?

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

I am working on Parcelable class for storing data into arraylist and pass from one activity to other activity.but parcelable model class contain android component textview so, how can I read that component in parcelable class?

[image]

***Your answer would be appreciated.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. You cannot pass a `View` between processes, which is a requirement of `Parcelable`.

Have `CustBean` hold a `String`, which contains the text that had been in the `TextView` in the first activity, so the second activity can create its own `TextView` to show that `String` to the user.

Comment: can I store view in serializable?

Comment: @Vasant: No, sorry. Pass the `String`, not the `TextView`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put into Plain Old Java Object Android-specific views such as `TextView`.
Read the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html

Comment: can I store view in serializable?

Comment: @Vasant No, you can't. Neither you need, you can simply fill your POJOs with constructors in which you will send your textView.getText() or smth like that.

Answer (score 3):

The `TextView` is not Parcelable, therefore it cannot be parcelled.

It has a reference to a `Context` anyways, so the notion of putting it into a data object and sending it to one place from another is somewhat ridiculous. You get pretty much the same thing by sending `textView.getText()`.

Comment: can I store view in serializable?

Comment: I don't see why you would. You should just send over the text, and if your textview's state (for example color, text size, etc.) depends on state, then send over your state, and create the textview in the new activity in its layout. By the way, `Context` is not serializable, so no.

Comment: because of textview dynamically create according to list of data available in array list.arraylist keep size of data varied so,

Comment: Then use an `ArrayList<T>` to represent the data, and use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` to display the data based on the list...

Comment: need to display one activity to other activity.thats why i needed parcelable data.

Comment: Then parcel your **data**, and not your view